# When publishing to a user's Timeline (using open graph), can I use the application's access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So, Facebook has 2 types of access tokens: Application and User access token.

Is it possible to use the Application access token for open graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has more than two types of access tokens, there are at least 3 since you forgot to mention the [Page Access Token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/).

According to the [App Access Token documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/):

> Authenticating as an Application allows your application to obtain an
>   App Access Token. This is useful to make requests to the Graph API to
>   modify the parameters of your app, create and manage test users, or
>   read your application's insights for example.

As you can see, it depends what it is you want to ask the fb graph.
If you want for example to get the feed of a public page then an app token will suffice, on the other hand if you want to get the feed of a user then you'll have to use a user token.

When you browser through the [Graph API documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api), for every object you get a list of fields and connections, and the 3rd column of the tables is titled as *Permissions*, in that cell you'll have info of what access token is needed if any.

I.e., if you check out the [User object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) you can see:

- id: No access_token required
- updated_time: Requires access_token
- installed: Requires app access_token

Hope this clarifies things for you.